# Probability operation

Tags: probability

I'm reading a research paper and I came across this "equation" for lack of a better word.

[image]

The p here refers to probability. Besides that, as you can see in the yellow part, why is there a subtraction sign in between them? Shouldn't it be positive?

Comment: Yes, I think so too.

Comment: @user326159 it seems like it is such a trivial thing and this shouldn't be a mistake in an important paper.. so I was thinking I'm missing out on something very obvious